# Get day of week from pandas Series of epochs

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to convert a column of epoch time to the day of the week.
I have a Dataframe called df and my code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

df['epoch'] = (df['epoch']).to_string()
df['day'] = time.ctime(df['epoch'])
```

I tried astype() but it's not working.

So assuming I have a column (from a large data) of epoch time containing:

```
1536444331894
1536444363932
1536444386908
1540436500055
1536444443458
```

and so on...

I need the day in this column instead of the seconds:

```
Saturday
Saturday
Saturday
Thursday
Saturday
...
```

Comment: Your approach is all over the place. Why do you use `.to_string()`? Why are you using the `time` module for pandas Series?

Comment: Hi Sigal. Are you saying that you have a dataframe with an `epoch` column that has large integers which correspond to seconds since a given epoch? I am not entirely clear on what you want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas provides a vectorized method [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for datetime conversion. Your epochs are in milliseconds, so you'll need to pass a `unit='ms'` argument accordingly. From there, you can use `strftime` to extract the day.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['epoch'], unit='ms').dt.strftime('%A')

0    Saturday
1    Saturday
2    Saturday
3    Thursday
4    Saturday
Name: epoch, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for [pandas.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Combined with the [dayofweek attribute](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html).

You would need to do:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['epoch']).dt.dayofweek
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question.